# Xcode command line build gives "using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported" error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cordova, bridging-header

I have a cordova project which includes the following Swift framework https://cocoapods.org/pods/SevenPassSDK - when I build and archive from within Xcode everything works fine, however when I build on the command line with `xcodebuild` I receive the error `using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported`.

I have 2 questions, firstly, why does this error only manifest on the command line build? Secondly, how can I modify my project to avoid the error (I don't want to have to modify the framework as it provided by a third party).